# How to look for resources that are available in multiple languages?

Tags: self-learning, multiple-languages, listening

In order to efficiently learn multiple foreign languages simultaneously, I noticed that resources provided in multiple languages can act as a big help.

I have been using http://www.goethe-verlag.com/book2/ for some time, but now I would appreciate something more difficult in order to learn more vocabulary.

I guess that administrators of this site would like to avoid any "contest of learning resources" (because my question can be perceived as too broad). For that reason I am asking for a technique of searching rather than raw links.

To make my question less broad I would like to add: *How to find resources closer to my scope of interests? For instance it is: popular science, programming and technology.*

I would also like to focus mainly on listening resources but if none found I would appreciate reading resources too.

Comment: Please tell us the specific languages you want.

Comment: @AML For instance: Spanish/Italian, Russian/Ukrainian and Japanese

Comment: I'm don't know what you mean by "request for learning materials contest". Resource requests such as "Spanish-language materials for learning Italian" (i.e. source lang = Spanish) would be on-topic. Or do you mean "**How to look for resources that are available in multiple languages?**" Your current question isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 2):

Something else that is *very frequently* translated into *many* languages is religious scripture and religious publications in general. Here are some examples:

- [E-Sword](https://www.e-sword.net/) - A Bible Study tool with many free and premium versions of the Christian Bible in various languages, including some ones less frequently studied such as Samoan, Welsh, and Romanian. It also includes classical versions as well, so you can read the Hebrew Old Testament in Biblical Hebrew, the Septuagint (Old Testament in Ancient Greek), the Greek New Testament, and the Latin Vulgate.
- [Online Qur'an in Different Languages from Tanzeem ul Irshad](http://tanzeemulirshad.com/languages.php?id=1) - Translations of the Islamic holy book
- [LDS Scriptures (Bible, Book of Mormon, etc.) in various languages](http://scripturetools.net/availability)
- [Information on finding Jehovah's Witnesses' publications in different languages](https://www.jw.org/en/online-help/using-jw-org/find-content-in-different-language/)

More broadly, you can identify religious organizations or publishers and see what materials they have to offer. Many religious organizations are keen to "spread the Word" and make materials available at low or no cost to a wide audience, so you could walk into a church, attend a few services, and say, "Hey, by the way, you wouldn't happen to have copies of your *Statement of Faith* and *Order of Service* in Polish, would you?" You might just succeed, or possibly even make language learning *contacts*!

Some religions tend to be more insular, and tend to make their publications available only in a few languages, usually the languages typically spoken by their followers and/or traditional or holy languages. For example, if you call up a Jewish bookstore and ask them if they have a High Holy Days prayer book in Northern Ojibwe, they will probably tell you no, yet the Jehovah's Witnesses (which have a strong missionary focus) [have some publications available in that language](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/?contentLanguageFilter=ojb_x_nos).

You can also identify organizations *based* on the language you wish to learn. Obviously, if you want to learn Hebrew or Yiddish, Jewish organizations will probably have more than you can digest over your lifetime. Learning Arabic? See what your local mosque has. Studying German in the USA? Many publishers catering to the Amish and Mennonite communities in the USA make their publications available in German as well as English. Japanese - is there a Buddhist temple in your city?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question in order to share interesting thing I found recently. Unfortunately it doesn't satisfy my needs in 100% so I keep my original question still open.

Straight to the point, I have noticed that lots of *National Geographic* or *Discovery* documentaries were translated with a lector/dubbing into multiple languages. Lots of them are easily accessible for instance through services like *YouTube*. With some effort and a bit of luck it is possible to find the same document translated into two languages.

List of examples:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:National_Geographic_Channel_programs
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Discovery_Channel_shows
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cineflix_shows

After choosing interesting topic, it is usually possible to change language in Wikipedia to find the title of appropriate position in target language.